# Is there any way to guarantee asyncio.Task will be started immediately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio


l = asyncio.Lock()

async def test():
    print('locked' if l.locked() else 'unlocked')

    await l.acquire()
    # await asyncio.ensure_future(l.acquire())

    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    l.release()

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(test(), test())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

We start two `test()` coroutines, first of them immediately locks Lock by `l.acquire()`, second prints `locked` state. Output:

```
unlocked
locked
```

Everything changes if you will comment `await l.acquire()` line and uncomment next one. Output will be:

```
unlocked
unlocked
```

It happens because `l.acquire()` wrapped in Task starts after second `test()` was started.

Is there any way to make `l.acquire()` Task to be started as soon as possible, before second `test()` (and to get same output as in the original code)?

Comment: My guess would be that it's not possible, since the event loop pops the tasks out of the `_ready` deque in the same order they arrived in. In your example, this order is `main()`, `test()`, `test()`, `l.acquire()`. But why would you schedule `l.acquire()` as a task anyway?

Comment: @Vincent It's synthetic example, in real life I use something like `asyncio.gather(l1.acquire(), l2...)` to start parallel resources blocking, but it wraps coroutines in Tasks.

Comment: Alright, so it's related to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969075/synchronous-blocking-of-multiple-resources). Maybe `asyncio.gather` is not the right tool for the job...

Comment: @Vincent thanks, but that's my question too :) I need to solve this one to find answer to second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found solution. We need global lock that would suspend second task locked checking while first task starts:

```
import asyncio


l = asyncio.Lock()
check_lock = asyncio.Lock()

async def test():
    async with check_lock:
        print('locked' if l.locked() else 'unlocked')
        await asyncio.ensure_future(l.acquire())
        print('now', 'locked' if l.locked() else 'unlocked')

    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    l.release()

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(test(), test())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
unlocked
now locked
locked
# 1 second delay here
now locked
```

But here we get another problem: second task would be suspended while first task completely done, that's why we get 1 second delay before second locking. It was hard to see in original example (because `test()` wait for single lock), that's why I added second printing. But it can be important for [multiple locking of different resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969075/synchronous-blocking-of-multiple-resources) to start coroutine immediately: we should lock only creating task, but not it's awaiting. Creating task itself wouldn't start that task (and `l.acquire()`) immediately, we should return control to event loop. It can be done by `await asyncio.sleep(0)`. Here's final solution for original code:

```
import asyncio


l = asyncio.Lock()
check_lock = asyncio.Lock()

async def test():
    async with check_lock:
        print('locked' if l.locked() else 'unlocked')
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(l.acquire())  # only create task
        await asyncio.sleep(0)  # return control to event loop, it allows lock to be locked before task completed
        print('now', 'locked' if l.locked() else 'unlocked')  # would be printed immediately

    await task  # and now we can await for task done
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    l.release()

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(test(), test())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
unlocked
now locked
locked
# no delay here
now locked
```